# Showing that no interval homeomorphism can be expansive

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A homeomorphism of a compact metric space $f$ is expanding if there is an $r >0$ such that $d(f^n(x), f^n(y)) \geq r$ for some $n(x,y) \in \Bbb N$ and all $x \neq y$. Without loss of generality we can consider the interval $[0,1]$

This seems really trivial, but I've but stuck on it for a while. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- Show that if $f$ is expansive, then so is $f^2$.
- Show that $f^2$ must have only finitely many fixed points (it must of course have at least $2$).
- Why does this mean we can restrict ourselves to $f$ such that $f^2(x) > x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$?
- Why can such a function on the interval not be expansive?

Comment: The first is clear, can have $[\frac{1}{r}]$ (maybe $\pm 2$) fixed points, third follows since all homeo's are strictly greater or less than $x$, and an expansive one clearly is greater. I don't see the fourth?

Comment: @Functor Ever $f^2$-orbit has a limit if $f^2(x) > x$. What is the limit? Given some expansivity constant $r$ then, find two elements which always remain at most $r$ apart under iteration by $f^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by has a limit?

Comment: If $f^2(x)>x$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, then the sequence $((f^2)^n(x))_{n\geq 1}$ converges for any $x \in (0,1)$. What does this sequence converge to?

Comment: $0$ or $1$. I don't see what tells us?

Comment: $1$ specifically. And given an $r$, if you choose $x,y$ such that $d(1,x),d(1,y) < r$, then what do you know about $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50158/discussion-between-functor-and-dan-rust).